# Android tab layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'm having a bit of a problem with the Android tab layout. I've been trying to make a screen that holds 4 tabs, and a fragment beneath them, when a user presses each tab the fragment dynamically switches to another activity and the tabs stay static, my problem is that I tried to implement it with tab layout and it's deprecated in since Android 4.0, so I tried it with the action bar tabs but then I have the action bar that I don't want nor need.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to use action bar but to hide the action bar and show only the tabs?
2. Is there a way to use tab layout on Android 4.0 and higher versions?

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not really sure about whether you can achieve it or not but if you want to play around with the ActionBar, [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) would be one of the best places to start.
2. Just because it is deprecated, doesn't mean that you can't use tabs in Android 4+. ;)

   **You surely can use Tabs and TabLayout in Android 4+** and everything works perfectly(though you apparently should not as ActionBar is a must better option).

   I have tried it myself because even I prefer the TabLayout more than the ActionBar, and thankfully haven't run into any issues until now!

   The only thing you will notice is that Eclipse will draw a yellow line over the deprecated code (which you can obviously ignore or just choose to hide all deprecated warnings).

Answer (score 0):

1.Yes there is possibility.....you should try http://actionbarsherlock.com/

2.ActionBarSherlock works from sdk 7 to sdk 16